# Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2

I am currently working on VueJS with Webpack and SCSS. The problem I have is that whenever I try to import the SCSS file into the component:
`<style type="scss"> @import "/sass/pages/_initial.scss";</style>`

I get an error stating: `Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/sass/pages/_initial.scss' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Therefore it's not an issue with finding the file, it finds it.
The code there is quite simple and straightforward, just some SCSS:

```
#initial {
position: relative;
background-color: $primary-white;
}

.vid-play-one {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I am puzzled as to why it might do so, the mime type should be text/css

Comment: You need to import the rendered css file, not the scss file.

Comment: Try with `lang="scss"` attribute instead of `type`

Comment: Side note: what do you get when you type `http://localhost:8080/sass/pages/_initial.scss` in your browser address bar?

Comment: I'm not getting an error that the file can't be found, it simply loads the content of the index page. However, the solution Gavin provided actually worked, I tried lang="scss", instead of setting a type.

Answer (score 0):

Im using MiniCssExtractPlugin in WebPack and I realized missing '**.**' will caused below issue.

from

```
filename: '/style.[contenthash].css'
```

to

```
filename: './style.[contenthash].css'
```

```js
//correct way should be like this

new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  publicPath: './sass/',
  filename: './style.[contenthash].css'
});
```

Hope this help you.